# Android Opencv EM Fatal Error

Tags: android, opencv

I'm trying to use **EM::predict2(sample, probs)** to predict if a pixel is part of a leaf or not; however, I'm getting the error:

> CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/ml/src/em.cpp:569: error: (-215) sample.size() == Size(means.cols, 1) in function cv::Vec2d cv::ml::EMImpl::computeProbabilities(const cv::Mat&, cv::Mat*, int) const]

When I'm calling:

```
Mat mPredict = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8UC1);
Mat mLabel = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8UC1);
mPredict.put(0,0,imgHSV.get(i,j)[1]);
mLabel.put(0,0,imgHSV.get(i,j)[2]);

double[] probabilities = em.predict2(mPredict, mLabel);
```

To clarify some points, I'm showing below the pseudocode that I was trying to follow:

```
stackedPixels ← ∅
for all pixelRow in image do
    for all pixel in pixelRow do
        stackedPixels ← stackedPixels ∪ pixel
    end for
end for
EM ← OpenCV.EM(nClusters = 2, covMatT ype = OpenCV.DIAGONAL)
EM.train(stackedPixels)
return EM


key ← hash(pixel[S], pixel[V])
if hash in pixelDictionary then
    return pixelDictionary[key]
end if
probabilities ← EM.predict(pixel[S], pixel[V])
pixelDict[key] = probabilities[0] > probabilities[1]
return pixelDict[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of opencv ? they changed the method recently.
Maybe you can try this first? This is based on v3.1.0
https://github.com/sonnyky/OpenCVEM

I was playing around with OpenCV EM and managed to get it working to classify pixels within n clusters. It is still work under progress so forgive the messy code :)

Comment: I was using v3.2.0. However, I was going to take look to find if it can help me!